# Can you build W-types out of natural numbers predicatively?

Tags: dependent-type, natural-numbers, w-type

I understand that we can use W-types to encode natural numbers and a wide variety of other inductive types in intensional MLTT. Can we encode W-types using only natural numbers within type theory, potentially giving up some of the judgmental equalities, but keeping the propositional equality the same? I always thought it was the case based on this quote from [nLab W-type page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/W-type):

"In a topos with a natural numbers object (NNO), W-types for any polynomial endofunctor can be constructed as certain sets of well-founded trees; thus every topos with a NNO is a ΠW-pretopos. This applies in particular in the topos Set (unless one is a predicativist, in which case Set is not a topos and W-types in it must be postulated explicitly)."

But I am unsure if this is a correct interpretation of the categorical concepts involved. I think the culprit here is the requirement of a topos with NNO, not just a locally cartesian closed category.
Is this the case? Can we construct W-types from natural numbers?

Edit: I have found a construction of W-types from natural numbers in presence of propositional resizing in [Strictly Positive Types in
Homotopy Type Theory](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/%7Erech/bachelor/thesis.pdf), so I think I should specify that I want to keep the theory as predicative as possible and hopefully free of uses of K or univalence.

Edit 2: To specify what I mean by intensional MLTT, it is the rules for $\Pi$, $\Sigma$, $\mathbb{N}$, Id, 0, 1, 2, plus an infinite predicative hierarchy of universes. $U_0 : U_1$, $U_1 : U_2$ etc.

Comment: How much structure are you assuming, something like MLTT ($\Pi$, $\Sigma$, $\mathrm{Id}$, $\mathbb{N}$, $0$, $1$, $2$), possibly with universes?

Comment: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1377/153 apparently a generic construction is possible within simple type theory. However, I don't really understand the construction myself.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee That answer there only seems to address HOL-like settings, but HOL importantly lacks dependency and universes, note the signature of W (A : Set) (B : A -> Set) : Set, in HOL type families like B cannot be defined (we could still quantify over small A).

Comment: Just a comment that I think the n-lab quote you mentioned for toposes would be the HOL setting, right?, since iHOL is the internal language of a topos.  Your question for MLTT still makes sense, but one shouldn’t rely on that quote to say something specific about MLTT, right?

Comment: … Maybe this is exactly what you are saying in the paragraph after the quote.  If so, ignore my comment.

Comment: yes, that's what I am trying to say is that intensional MLTT + N should be an internal language of locally closed cartesian categories with NNO, not topos with an NNO, so the quote would only apply to stronger type theories/internal languages and won't tell us much about the W-types in internal language of LCCC+NNO.

Comment: Wikipedia's page on [ordinal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) says that the proof theoretic ordinal for MLTT without W-types (but with universes) is smaller than that for MLTT with W-types (even without universes). So, that suggests that you cannot build W-types with just ℕ and (predicative) universes. It's not very clear where all the information on that page comes from, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no. According to Anton Setzer's PhD thesis: [Proof theoretical strength of Martin-Löf Type Theory with W-type and one universe](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esetzer/articles/):

> Aczel has shown in [Acz77] that Martin-Löf’s type theory with one universe but no W-type has strength $| \widehat{ID}_1 | = \phi_{\epsilon_0}0$.

However:

> The strength we prove, is in fact far bigger [than that shown by Palmgren], it is slightly bigger than the strength of [$| KP_i|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory). Until recently (work of Rathjen, [Rat90], [Rat91a], [Rat92],
> see also [Buc93], [Sch91a], [Sch91b], [Sch92b]), $KP_i$ has been essentially the strongest theory, for which proof theoretical analysis could be carried out. For the author, $|KP_i|$ is an ordinal which seems to be an ordinal of significance similar to that of [$\Gamma_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feferman%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtte_ordinal)

Furthermore:

> Precisely we calculate the proof theoretical strength of intensional Russel, extensional, Tarski, and extensional Russel-version of Martin-Löf’s type theory with one Universe and the W-type, $ML^i_1W_R$ , $ML^e_1W_T$ and $ML^e_1 W_R$, namely $$|ML^i_1W_R| =|ML^e_1W_T|=|ML^e_1 W_R|= |\bigcup_{n\in{\mathbb N}}KPi_n^+| = \psi_{\Omega_1}\Omega_{I+\omega}.$$

This sorts out the proof theoretical strength for MLTT with a single universe.

Now, according to Michael Rathjen's paper [The strength of Martin-Löf type theory with a superuniverse](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/Super.pdf) (which is at least stronger than MLTT with an infinite hierarchy of universes):

> the proof-theoretic ordinal of $MLS$ is $\Phi_{\Gamma_0}0$

But according to the wikipedia page on [ordinal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis), as pointed out by Dan Doel,
$$\phi_{\epsilon_0}0 < \Gamma_0 < \Phi_{\Gamma_0}0 < \psi_{\Omega_1}\Omega_{I+\omega}$$

And therefore $|ML_\omega| < |ML_1W|$ thus it cannot be possible to encode W-types in $ML_\omega$.